# How to loop through each div with specific class using javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, css, for-loop

I'm trying to make a search for FAQ page that will hide the results that dont have the keywords that user typed in. Right now the search is only highlighting the keywords and I assigned divs for each question with the class "faq-question". So I'm trying to loop through each div with class "faq-question", detect if the keyword that user searched is there (those keywords assigned tag "mark") and then change the background of this section if div="faq-question" contains the `<mark>` tag inside. My code right now is highlighting ALL the divs="faq-question" instead of those that have `<mark>` inside. How would I fix this?

HTML

```
<input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="Search on the page..."></input>
<div class="faq-question"><h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<p></div>
<div class="faq-question"><h4>Why do we use it?</h4>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p></div>
```

Javascript:

```
//Hide unrelated search results
var question = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");
var keyword = document.querySelector("mark");


for(x = 0; x < question.length; x++) {
    if(typeof(keyword) != 'undefined' && keyword != null){
        question[x].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
        console.log("shown");
    } else {
        question[x].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        console.log("hidden");
    }
}
```

Edit: the `<mark>` tag is a dynamic value. The question is about loop, but just to be clear: for example you type in "lorem" in the `<input id="keywords">`. Then the html will change to

```
<h4>What is <mark>Lorem</mark> Ipsum?</h4>
```

...And so on. So I only use `<mark>` tag in this case to detect if div has the keywords that match to whatever user was searching for

Comment: keyword is not going to be undefined, that check is useless. You do nothing with the keyword so not sure what you are trying to do? Look at the text for a match?

Comment: Do you really have a `<mark>` element?

Comment: `@maroun` it's better you can share the HTML structure as well.

Comment: just added the html. <mark> tag is assigned by the Hilitor framework that I use. So whatever user types in gets wrapped in <mark> tag and gets highlighted like ctrl+f. In this case I just use mark to check if typed in the search keyword matches the div contents

Comment: Not sure how the `mark` tag is important to the question - only because either the question in the loop has the keyword(s) or it doesn't, right?

Comment: So what does `questions` have to do with `mark`..... I am not getting the relationship.... Does mark exist inside of the question? Is there just one? Remember that we have ZERO clue about what you are doing and all we can see is what is in the question.

Comment: I have it in question description. <mark> is dynamic value. Whatever you type in input and matches anything on the page gets wrapped in <mark>. I will update the question to be more clear

Comment: so you are selecting ONE mark out of all of them..... still no clue what it has to do with the elements.  Is  the `<mark>` element inside of the `faq-question`? `document.querySelectorAll(".faq-question").forEach( function (elem) {
   const hasMarks = elem.querySelectorAll("mark").length > 0;
   elem.classList.toggle("hasMatch", hasMarks);
});`

Comment: @epascarello dont worry about "mark". My code detects if "mark" tag is present on the page `if(typeof(keyword) != 'undefined' && keyword != null)` and then it changes the background of all the "faq-question" divs, because i select all of them `question[x]`. I need to check `if(typeof(keyword) != 'undefined' && keyword != null)` against the `question` and not the whole page, and that's where I'm stuck

Comment: @Maroun so what I wrote in my comment would work. :) Toggles a class if there is a mark.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just simple miss spelled. You declared variable as questions so Inside the for loop should be **questions** not **question**

So code will be

```
<input type="text" id="keywords" placeholder="Search on the page..."></input>
<div class="faq-question"><h4>What is <mark>Lorem Ipsum?<mark></h4>
<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.<p></div>
<div class="faq-question"><h4>Why do we use it?</h4>
<p>It is a long established fact that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p></div>

    var questions = document.getElementsByClassName("faq-question");


    for(x = 0; x < questions.length; x++) {
    if(questions[x].getElementsByTagName('mark').length){
        questions[x].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFF00";
        console.log("shown");
    } else {
        questions[x].style.backgroundColor = "#FFFFFF";
        console.log("hidden");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for noticing, But that does not fix the problem

Comment: Go it what you need, Let get the answer to you

Comment: Thank you so much! Works like charm!

Answer (score 0):

Select all the questions, check to see if the element exists as a child, if it does, toggle a class.

```js
document.querySelectorAll(".faq-question").forEach(function(elem) {
  const hasMarks = elem.querySelectorAll("mark").length > 0;
  elem.classList.toggle("hasMatch", hasMarks);
});
```

```css
.hasMatch {
  background-color: lime;
}
```

```html
<div class="faq-question">
  <h4>What is Lorem Ipsum?</h4>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry.
    <p>
</div>
<div class="faq-question">
  <h4>Why do we use it?</h4>
  <p>It is a long established <mark>fact</mark> that a reader will be distracted by the readable content of a page when looking at its layout.</p>
</div>
```